# find sum of the squares of the digits of a number in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I need to write a function in scheme which calculates the sum of square digits.

```
ex - (sum-of-digits 130)
    > 10
```

This is my function.

```
(define (sum-of-digits x)
      (if (= x 0) 0
          (+ (modulo x 10) (sum-of-digits (/ (- x (modulo x 10)) 10)))))
```

it doesn't work for some numbers. When I entered (sum-of-digits 130) , it returns 4. How can i fix this ?

Also I need to use this function to find the stop numbers which are 0,1,4,16,20,37,42,58,89,145

```
ex :- (stop? 42)
 #t

(stop? 31)
 #f
```

How can I do this using the function sum of sum-of-digits above?

Comment: How do you define `stop?`? what's the rule to determine if a number is `#t` for it?

Comment: For the second part of your question: this looks like sequence [A039943](https://oeis.org/A039943), but basically _all_ integers end up in the sequence when repeatedly adding the square of the digits. So, the `stop?` procedure will always be `#t`.

Comment: the stop? returns #t for 42 because 4^2+2^2= 20 and 20 is one of the stop numbers.  And 31 returns #f because 3^2+1^2= 10 and 10 is not a stop number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to actually *square* each digit, and there's a simpler way to obtain the quotient:

```
(define (sum-of-digits x)
  (if (= x 0) 
      0
      (+ (sqr (modulo x 10))
         (sum-of-digits (quotient x 10)))))
```

For the second part of the question:

```
(define (stop? x)
  (let ((sum (sum-of-digits x)))
    (if (member sum '(0 1 4 16 20 37 42 58 89 145)) #t #f)))
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! Also do you know how I use this function to track numbers 0,1,4,16,20,37,42,58,89,145 and return true for them (second part of the question) ?

Comment: Please explain, what do you mean with "track numbers"? How do I know if `stop?` returns `#f` for a number?

Comment: stop returns #t if sum-of-digits series always reach one of the following numbers: 0,1,4,16,20,37,42,58,89,145

Comment: If I understand correctly, _all_ integers will end up in that sequence if we repeatedly apply `sum-of-digits` over its digits. For your example: `3^2 + 1^2 = 10`, `1^2 + 0^2 = 1`, and `1` is in the sequence. But if we apply `sum-of-digits` only once, then yes, there are numbers not in the sequence. I updated my answer for that case.