# returning a list and check conditions in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I have a function sum-of-digits which calculates the sum of square digits
And stop function which check if sum-of-digits series always reach one of the stop numbers. {0 1 4 16 20 37 42 58 89 145}

How do i make a function called 's_series' that returns a list containing sum-of-digits until a stop number is reached.

```
ex :- (s_series 130)
 (10 1)
```

My code

```
    (define (s_series x)
    (let ((number (sum-of-digits x)))
(if (number stop(number) 1)
     ((let (L '(sum)))
      (s_series sum ))
      L
     ))
```

how can i fix this and make it work ?

Comment: This is a follow-up to your [previous](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42958757/201359) question. Post _your own code_ and the specific problems you're having with it, otherwise people will think you're just trying to get your homework done for free...

Comment: Your code has many syntax errors in it. Eg. you have a `(if test)` with no `then` and `else` expression. Several values are called as a function because of excess parentheses. eg. `((let ...))` means that `(let ...)` needs to return a function since ti gets called with no arguments,  `(sum)` is calling the function `sum` with no arguments. Thus `(sosd x)` needs to return a function for it to work. `'(sum)` is a list with a symbol. It has nothing to do with the variable `sum` (that might be a function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended approach is, of course, to use existing procedures (such as `unfold`) to solve your problem. That's the way of thinking encouraged by functional programming. For completeness' sake, let's see how we could write an equivalent solution using only basic operations, and the procedures we [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42959939/201359) defined:

```
(define (s_series n)
  (let ((sum (sum-of-digits n)))
    (if (stop? n)
        (list sum)
        (cons sum (s_series sum)))))
```

It works as expected:

```
(s_series 120)
=> '(5 25 29 85 89)
```

Answer (score 1):

First off If you are collecting the `sum-of-squared-digits` then the `stop?` function should take such sum and not calculate it directly:

```scm
(define (stop? value)
  (if (memv value '(0 1 4 16 20 37 42 58 89 145)) #t #f))
```

Notice I use `memv` since we know we are comparing numbers and `memv` uses `eqv?` to compare and thus is the right "member" function for the job. Also I don't use `sum-of-squared-digits` here to not do the operation twice for each element.

In the SRFI-1 List Library there is a function called `unfold`:

```scm
(require srfi/1) ; In #!r6rs you import (srfi :1) but I assume #lang racket

(define (s-series start)
  (unfold stop?                         ; stop if the sum is accodring to stop?
          values                        ; no term transformation
          sum-of-squared-digits         ; how to make th enext value
          (sum-of-squared-digits start) ; omit the first value 
          (lambda (v) (list v))))       ; keep the stop value

(s-series 120)
; ==> (5 25 29 85 89)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using the unfold function ?

Comment: @user7630822 Yes, but why not use the tools available? The implementation of `unfold` does the recursion for you.